# How can I compare incoming video to images in a folder?

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to make a program that needs to view an incoming video feed in real time through
a capture card or other video receiving device. I pretty much have no clue where to start with this. I looked into OpenCV but anything I found relating to it had to do with UI and I am not that familiar with javax and would rather just keep it simple for now. If OpenCV requires a UI then I will have to learn how to utilize javax, but I haven't been able to find any consistent information about that. I plan to translate this to a UI at some given point anyway, but I would rather get the program functional first before moving on to a UI.

The goal of my program is to look at the HUD of a game and detect what power-up is being
displayed in that region of the HUD. The images themselves in the HUD are pretty distinct, here are examples of the images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN5pF.jpg

If you are familiar with the game in question, this may be easier to understand...
The game cycles through all 23 power-ups on a randomly set cycle twice (called a "mix"), so the program's job is to make it easier to get the power-up you want by starting a timer once the second cycle starts that gives the player an easier opportunity to press "A" on the given power-up. The user starts the program manually once they initiate the mix

So my order of operations are basically as follows:

- The user inputs a number (1-23) to choose what powerup they are searching for
- The user manually starts the seeking process in the program window once they initiate the mix
- The program focuses on the bottom left corner of the screen and "captures" the screen in real-time if it detects an image change in the HUD, this change happens once every 4 frames (65.32ms)
- On every capture, the program compares the capture to 23 images of the HUD to find which power is being shown at that current moment.
- This image is then "converted" to an integer and stored in an array, which allows the order to be stored and utilized later.

As much as I would love to know how to code this, my main question is **if** this is even possible within the confines of Java.
I am not sure where to start and if this task is too complicated for this language, and if it is possible to constantly grab images from a video feed this quickly. I am basically looking to grab an image every 4 frames 60fps, which is pretty quick. I also just generally want to know how practical this would be and if it will be difficult for the process to be consistent when it comes to comparing the images.

The main things I would like to know is how to compare video feed with an image, and how to only focus on a specific area of the video feed to compare the image with.

This is the program I currently made, which is a proof of concept for what I am looking to do:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

    private static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int powerList[] = new int[23];
    public static int videoFeed[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23};
    //videoFeed[] is meant as a placeholder for the actual video feed that the program would be viewing


    /*
    Power List:
    01 - Sword   02 - Cutter  03 - Leaf    04 - Whip    05 - Fire    06 - Needle
    07 - Beam    08 - Spark   09 - Stone   10 - Sleep   11 - Parasol 12 - Water
    13 - Hi-jump 14 - Tornado 15 - Bomb    16 - Spear   17 - Hammer  18 - Ice
    19 - Wing    20 - Ninja   21 - Fighter 22 - Crash   23 - Mike
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("This program is a proof of concept for mix detecting.");
        System.out.println("The end goal is to connect your video capture to this program and have it scan mix cycles, then countdown to help you time mixes.");
        System.out.println("The program will randomly generate a power order as a proof of concept");
        System.out.println("Please input the power-up number to search for (1-23):");
        int target = input.nextInt();
        //Include error handling later

        //If needed, display prompts for configuring video input device

        int counter = 0;
        boolean found = false;

        //Simulation of obtaining power-up order from video feed
        //This block will not be in actual program as the scanning will be real-time and included in next block
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < powerList.length; i++) {
            int randomIndexToSwap = rand.nextInt(powerList.length);
            int temp = videoFeed[randomIndexToSwap] = videoFeed[i];
            videoFeed[i] = temp;
        }
        System.out.println("Simulated power order: " + Arrays.toString(videoFeed));

        //Scanning in real-time:
        //Reading the videoFeed array should be replaced with scanning the video feed and finding what power is there
        System.out.println("Scanning mix...");
        while (!found) {
            for (int i = 0; i < powerList.length; i++) {
                counter++;
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep((long) 65.32);
                //Image scanning algorithm would go here, placeholder for now
                powerList[i] = videoFeed[i];
                //convert image to integer number for power-up, would possibly go here
                if (target == powerList[i]) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        //The rest of the program will be fine for me if the images will be translated into integers
    }
}
```

Comment: matchTemplate with a "haystack" cropped to the same size as the "needle". that'll give you a cheap sum of differences, if you use the right mode. it also accepts a mask argument. use it, if you have background to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

If detecting what power up is currently displayed in the hud is your issue then that actually sounds simple enough.

No matter how you're dealing with images, you'd need to compare their pixel values at matching positions to tell what powerup is active. But you can't just directly compare the powerup image to the hud image since the background of the hud is variable and will not match; You'd need to ignore comparing transparent pixels of the powerup image.

However, that may not be necessary anyway.. you might get away with sampling and comparing just a few or even a single pixel!

If you can find a pixel that is unique among all the powerups then you only need to check that one. If there's no single unique pixel, then you might need to use a few to uniquely idetify the powerups. It's worth a shot to check anyway.

Comment: if all that I would need to do is compare a very small area / a single pixel, it would make this whole process much easier, so thank you for explaining that to me. Are there any documents / websites I can read that could go over where I could start with doing such a thing?